# Amplify Auth.verifyTotpToken - user.verifySoftwareToken is not a function

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, totp

AWS Amplify - Cogito MFA TOTP

Iam trying to sign in with TOTP enabled.
I already setup TOTP. and getting a right reponse.

![cogintoUser]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VXpz.jpg - cognitoUser (object)

```
Auth.verifyTotpToken(cogintoUser, form.code).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

This is the error what i get.
TypeError: user.verifySoftwareToken is not a function

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, or someone else comes across this, odds are that you didn't use a valid Cognito user object to make that call.

You can use the `currentAuthenticatedUser` method to get the proper user object, and then use that to make your `verifyTotpToken` call. The docs for the method [can be found here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#retrieve-current-authenticated-user).